When does Chrome decide to show a number to indicate number of duplicate console.log() calls?
I noticed Chrome DevTools will show a number before the output of a console.log() if it's called multiple times.
However, I noticed it will show the same console.log() call on a new line in some situations.
I have a React app and am calling console.log() in the useEffect() hook:
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('rendered!');
  });

When I type the letter 'a' in the input, it shows 'rendered!', then if I click the button to add the item, it shows 'rendered!' on a new line:

However, if I continue typing in the first input, I then see 'rendered!' on a new line again, but a number is displayed to indicate multiple calls to console.log() with the same output.
Here I've typed 'abc' which resulted in 3 calls to the useEffect() hook.

Why does typing in the input result in a number indicating the number of calls made for that particular string, why does it then put it on a new line when I click a button?

There is a "Group similar" setting turned on by default I think.
